# What exactly is meant by "Eliminate dead keys"?

Tags: system-installation, keyboard-layout

When I choose my country (Norway) I get two options:

- Norway
- Norway - Eliminate dead keys

What is meant by "Eliminate dead keys"? What does that do? Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are keys like the hat (<kbd>^</kbd>) or other French accents. These only take effect after pressing another regular key on your keyboard. One could say they simply modify the second key pressed. Those keys are called "[dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_keys)" and are a special variety of the "[modifier keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key)". They are dead in the sense that nothing happens when you press them by themselves. Until you press another key (or press them a second time), you will not see any change.

Example for the French "accent circonflexe" (aka. hat or circumflex `^`) on a regular **layout with dead keys**:

<kbd>^</kbd>  -->  results in nothing

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd> -->  results in --> `â`

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>^</kbd> --> results in --> `^`

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd> --> results in --> `^a`

"Eliminate dead keys" causes those so called "[diacritic marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)" to appear on the first keypress (not modifying the character typed after that).

Same example with **"Eliminate dead keys" layout**:

<kbd>^</kbd>  -->  results in --> `^`

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd> --> results in --> `^a`

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>^</kbd> --> results in --> `^^`

<kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>^</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd> --> results in --> `^^a`

The main purpose of dead keys is to enable you to type seldom used characters easily without taking up too much space on the keyboard. On my keyboard I would type a Norwegian (Norse) `å` with the combination <kbd>°</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: A well written and an instructive answer!

Comment: Does that mean that with "Eliminate dead keys" selected, I wouldn't be able to type an `â` if I needed to?

Comment: With "Norway - Eliminate dead keys" you can only type `^a`. With your normal "Norway" keyboard though you can type `â` by first pressing the `^` located to the right of your `Å` and then typing a regular `a`.

Comment: Deal. Guess I might have to go with the regular then. Thanks for good answer :)

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by mentioning that you can bind a compose key that still enables you to input the type of characters enabled by the dead keys. I don't trust my own writing skills to add it to the answer, but would very much approve if someone does.

Comment: never heard of a "compose key"

Comment: I presume what is meant is the <kbd>alt-graph</kbd> + code combination on Windows or the <kbd>shif</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> combination in Ubuntu that allows you to insert any Unicode character 