# Use accents with Japanese keyboard layout in Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, internationalization

I would like to use french accents using the Japanese keyboard layout. Dead keys would be great, but I am willing to accept key combinations too. I just would not like to switch the layout, because that will confuse the location of other punctation symbols. So far I was unable to find the right key combinations in Kubuntu. Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Stéphane (which I wrote by googling my name and copy-pasting :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Japanese keyboards use a QWERTY layout just as in the US and UK layouts, it should be possible to use multiple key combinations to type French characters such as é (as used in your name). This was achieved using the key combination <kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>'</kbd>.
Special Characters from Linux Keyboard

RightWindows key latches then press keys in sequence using shift where necessary for correct symbol.

A more complete list is reproduced below. I have assigned <kbd>Right Win</kbd> as the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had to enable the compose key as described here: https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey/en#Current_KDE_Configuration
Just wondering: is it possible to use dead keys as well, or is that only possible using the US-International keyboard layout?

Comment: @Stéphane This answer about dead keys might be useful to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56560/what-exactly-is-meant-by-eliminate-dead-keys

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is no 'Japanese - with deadkeys' layout.