# Use Japanese input method with accents on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, kde, japanese, fcitx

Ever since I upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04, the compose key in KDE stopped working. I cannot write accents anymore because of this. It resembles a similar issue I encountered in the past:
[Use accents with Japanese keyboard layout in Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087976/use-accents-with-japanese-keyboard-layout-in-kubuntu)

I am a bit confused on fcitx, ibus, mozc etc. What approach do you recommend for Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You should select a Latin language to use a compose key. Japanese input method doesn't have a compose key. I can tell, the Japanese input method is the thing which compose key is always on.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But is there a way to easily switch between a Latin language and the Japanese IME then? In Kubuntu 20.04, I could just press the dedicated button on my keyboard for this (labeled 半角/全角 and 漢字).

Comment: Also crucial: my keyboard is actually a Japanese one, so the US International layout does not work (I noticed that the ' above the 7 is actually typing &, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I had to install fcitx5 and related packages (frontend packages for qt, gtk3/4 etc.).
Also had to be careful not to install fcitx (without 5).
Then Chromium still did not work, but that was resolved by running 'im-config' and manually specifying fcitx5 there (instead of automatic, which was selecting ibus).
Now the compose key is working when switching to Japanese keyboard layout without mozc. I can switch back to mozc by pressing the '半角/全角|漢字' button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a window of fcitx configurations.

- Japanese IME ON  - Green circle
- Japanese IME OFF - Red circle
- Japanese IME Toggle - Green line

If you are using two languages back and forth, then it is handy to assign each key to change into.
日本語キーボードには、変換と無変換キーがスペースの両脇にあります
Mac日本語キーボードはその両脇のキーでアルファベットとひらがな打鍵の切り替えを行うように設定されています、これは大変便利だった記憶があります