# Unexpected behavior when typing accents (´, `, ^) on Spanish Layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

So I've had Ubuntu 20.04 installed for a while but I've run into an issue I hadn't really noticed before. I started programming in Python, and writing papers in LaTeX recently, and which requires an extended use of the circumflex/hat (`^`) key followed by either numbers, or curly braces `{...}`. I have a [Spanish keyboard layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/KB_Spanish.svg) where, as you can see, the hat is obtained by pressing `Shift` + the key to the right of P.

The problem I'm encountering is that in Ubuntu, when I press that key, the character appears underlined awaiting my next input [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcgRZ.jpg) (apologize for photo of screen, it disappears when I press any other key),  and one of four things happens:

- I press a vowel which results in it being typed with the accent on top, this is expected behavior: â
- I press the spacebar or the same key again, and the accent appears on its own, which is what I would need when typing LaTeX: ^, but this requires an extra unnecessary input.
- When I press the key and follow it by either a consonant or the curly braces `{}`, **the accent disappears**. This is unexpected and undesired behavior: I would like it to work the same way it does on Windows, which will type the two characters like so `^{`, `^n`...
- Or I follow it with a number which results in the superscript being input directly: ², which is totally useless in any programming context since it will not be processed to mean the same thing as `^2` (R, Python, LaTeX...).

The same thing happens when trying to input ` on its own which I would also like to behave in the same way as the hat key.

I have tried changing my layout to different versions of Spanish (Win keys, dead tilde...) but it has not solved the issue. Does anybody have any suggestions as to what could be done about this?

Thank you!

---

EDIT: I have found a "workaround" that I will post as an answer if I can't find a way to get the exact behavior I want (replicating the way Windows does it).

I found the explanation of dead keys [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/56562/1116191), which prompted me to choose the "Spanish (no dead keys)" layout. This gives me a behavior I am happy with in a programming context: `, ´, ^ are typed automatically, without the need to double-press the keys, or press the space-bar.

My only issue with this is that when typing in Spanish I can't automatically type the accent on vowels like we do in Spain (á, é, í, ó, ú), so I am using the compose key for this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en#compose.

I'm not 100% satisfied with this workaround since it still requires an extra key press when typing those accented letters that isn't required when typing in Windows. This is why I am not posting my own answer yet in the hopes somebody can offer the right solution.

Thank you again!

Comment: So you figured out the difference between dead keys and 'normal' keys. Using a non-dead-key layout when programming and a regular layout when typing other stuff appears to me to be a reasonable solution. Your description makes me wonder a bit about what kind of magic you mean that Windows does.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it isn't magic, and I guess it might just be a different way of doing things I have to get used to but: on Windows when I press an accent key there's one of two ways it goes:

I follow it with a vowel in which case it types á, é...
I follow it with any other keypress (except backspace) which types out the accent (or hat) separately ´t, ´1...

Comment: I thought a bit more about it. GNOME comes with an on-screen keyboard which you can access via _Settings -> Universal Access_, and with that tool, if you long press a letter, you can choose from a list of various accented letters. However, the XKB keyboard layouts don't include any equivalent functionality AFAIK.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the **spanish** no dead key layout, but on some (I'm thinking of US International with AltGr dead keys), the key that were 'dead' are now available as `AltGr` keystroke. Something to try? Or else: request someone to change the layout you use now?

Comment: I took a look at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es` and, unfortunately, the `no dead key` variant removes the dead keys altogether. So, the AltGr trick won't work. But why are there two keys that generate `{`? What does the key cap on key AD11 (grave, asciicircum) say?

Comment: @ini I could not find a solution to this. It is very inconvenient as I end up putting accent on consonants, when writing in English, such as itś or Iḿ or thatś instead of it's or I'm or that's

Comment: I would say you never used a mechanical typewriter machine. Didn't you, huh?