# How to disable pre-edit text for accents and tildes?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout, gtk

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with a Spanish layout keyboard. When I type a spanish accent `´` or a carat `^`, it is displayed with an underscore waiting for another key press similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcgRZ.jpg) (image borrowed from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266790/unexpected-behavior-when-typing-accents-%C2%B4-on-spanish-layout)).

I would like to **disable this preview** and use it like in Windows: when pressed, it doesn't do anything (no preview is printed on screen) until the next key is pressed.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My keyboard layout is set to *Spanish* and my system language to *English (US)*.

Comment: the character is not tilde ~, its a carat ^. [edit] your question with more detail about what you have set for both `Keyboard` and `Language and Region`

Comment: FWIW that sounds as a rather recent change to GTK. I'm not aware of an easy way to to disable the preedit behavior, though. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/commit/5c6aa769

Answer (score 0):

This pre-edit behavior was introduced by [Ibus, an input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus).

Since Ibus might not be running or even installed, GTK (a GUI toolkit, not an input method!) [decided to mimic](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/3669) that behavior.

But you are not out of luck, because you can [override the desired input method with the GTK_IM_MODULE environment variable *(note: this links to my own content in a site that I moderate)*](https://linux.codidact.com/posts/285653/285654#answer-285654), and good old [X Input Method, Xim](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/3669), is true to the old consolidated behavior of displaying no symbol at all for dead keys.

Comment: I looked at your link and I don't seem to have installed the command `gtk-query-immodules-3.0` to list the input methods available. The closest I have is `gtk-query-settings`. Should I install something extra?
Also, it would be useful to list the steps in your answer for future reference.